# Getting an error when integrated django-private-chat in the django project?

Tags: django, django-apps

I am working on an application where I want to implement the django-private-chat in for one to one messaging feature after I did everything which is said in the documentation I ran the server and got to the link http://127.0.0.1:8000/dialogs/ I am getting this error please help me out I have included the error traceback also[image]

dialogs.html:

```
% extends "base.html" %
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block css %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <link href="{% static "django_private_chat/css/django_private_chat.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
{% endblock css %}

{% block content %}
    <input id="owner_username" type="hidden" value="{{ request.user.username }}">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="user-list-div">
                <ul>
                    {% for dialog in object_list %}
                        <li>
                            {% if dialog.owner == request.user %}
                                {% with dialog.opponent.username as username %}
                                    <a href="{% url 'dialogs_detail' username %}" id="user-{{ username }}"
                                       class="btn btn-danger">{% trans "Chat with" %} {{ username }}</a>
                                {% endwith %}
                            {% else %}
                                {% with dialog.owner.username as username %}
                                    <a href="{% url 'dialogs_detail' username %}" id="user-{{ username }}"
                                       class="btn btn-danger">{% trans "Chat with" %} {{ username }}</a>
                                {% endwith %}
                            {% endif %}
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
                    <span class="pull-right" hidden id="typing-text">
                        <strong>{{ opponent_username }} {% trans "is typing..." %}</strong>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <p>
                    {{ opponent_username }}
                </p>
                <p class="text-success" id="online-status" style="display: none">{% trans "Online" %}</p>
                <p class="text-danger" id="offline-status" style="display: none">{% trans "Offline" %}</p>

                <div class="messages-container">
                    <div id="messages" class="messages">
                        {% for msg in active_dialog.messages.all %}
                            <div class="row {% if msg.read %}msg-read{% else %}msg-unread{% endif %}"
                                 data-id="{{ msg.id }}">
                                <p class="{% if msg.sender == request.user %}pull-left{% else %}pull-right{% endif %}">
                                    <span class="username">{{ msg.sender.username }}:</span>
                                    {{ msg.text }}
                                    <span class="timestamp">&ndash; <span
                                            data-livestamp="{{ msg.get_formatted_create_datetime }}">{{ msg.get_formatted_create_datetime }}</span></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="add-message">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea id="chat-message" class="form-control message"
                                  placeholder="{% trans 'Write a message' %}"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group clearfix">
                        <input id="btn-send-message" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right send-message"
                               style="margin-left: 10px;" value="{% trans 'Send' %}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_js %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/scrollmonitor/1.2.0/scrollMonitor.js"
            integrity="sha256-BseZlDlA+yL4qu+Voi82iFa5aaifralQEXIjOjaXgeo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        var base_ws_server_path = "{{ ws_server_path }}";
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var websocket = null;
            var monitor = null;

            function initReadMessageHandler(containerMonitor, elem) {
                var id = $(elem).data('id');
                var elementWatcher = containerMonitor.create(elem);
                elementWatcher.enterViewport(function () {
                    var opponent_username = getOpponnentUsername();
                    var packet = JSON.stringify({
                        type: 'read_message',
                        session_key: '{{ request.session.session_key }}',
                        username: opponent_username,
                        message_id: id
                    });
                    $(elem).removeClass('msg-unread').addClass('msg-read');
                    websocket.send(packet);
                });
            }

            function initScrollMonitor() {
                var containerElement = $("#messages");
                var containerMonitor = scrollMonitor.createContainer(containerElement);
                $('.msg-unread').each(function (i, elem) {
                    if ($(elem).hasClass('opponent')){
                        initReadMessageHandler(containerMonitor, elem);
                    }

                });
                return containerMonitor
            }

            function getOpponnentUsername() {
                return "{{ opponent_username }}";
            }

            // TODO: Use for adding new dialog
            function addNewUser(packet) {
                $('#user-list').html('');
                packet.value.forEach(function (userInfo) {
                    if (userInfo.username == getUsername()) return;
                    var tmpl = Handlebars.compile($('#user-list-item-template').html());
                    $('#user-list').append(tmpl(userInfo))
                });
            }

            function addNewMessage(packet) {
                var msg_class = "";
                if (packet['sender_name'] == $("#owner_username").val()) {
                    msg_class = "pull-left";
                } else {
                    msg_class = "pull-right";
                }
                var msgElem =
                    $('<div class="row msg-unread" data-id="' + packet.message_id + '">' +
                        '<p class="' + msg_class + '">' +
                        '<span class="username">' + packet['sender_name'] + ': </span>' +
                        packet['message'] +
                        ' <span class="timestamp">&ndash; <span data-livestamp="' + packet['created'] + '"> ' + packet['created'] + '</span></span> ' +
                        '</p> ' +
                        '</div>');
                $('#messages').append(msgElem);
                scrollToLastMessage()
            }

            function scrollToLastMessage() {
                var $msgs = $('#messages');
                $msgs.animate({"scrollTop": $msgs.prop('scrollHeight')})
            }

            function generateMessage(context) {
                var tmpl = Handlebars.compile($('#chat-message-template').html());
                return tmpl({msg: context})
            }

            function setUserOnlineOffline(username, online) {
                var elem = $("#user-" + username);
                if (online) {
                    elem.attr("class", "btn btn-success");
                } else {
                    elem.attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                }
            }

            function gone_online() {
                $("#offline-status").hide();
                $("#online-status").show();
            }

            function gone_offline() {
                $("#online-status").hide();
                $("#offline-status").show();
            }

            function flash_user_button(username) {
                var btn = $("#user-" + username);
                btn.fadeTo(700, 0.1, function () {
                    $(this).fadeTo(800, 1.0);
                });
            }

            function setupChatWebSocket() {
                var opponent_username = getOpponnentUsername();
                websocket = new WebSocket(base_ws_server_path + '{{ request.session.session_key }}/' + opponent_username);

                websocket.onopen = function (event) {
                    var opponent_username = getOpponnentUsername();

                    var onOnlineCheckPacket = JSON.stringify({
                        type: "check-online",
                        session_key: '{{ request.session.session_key }}',
                        username: opponent_username
                        {#                      Sending username because the user needs to know if his opponent is online #}
                    });
                    var onConnectPacket = JSON.stringify({
                        type: "online",
                        session_key: '{{ request.session.session_key }}'

                    });

                    console.log('connected, sending:', onConnectPacket);
                    websocket.send(onConnectPacket);
                    console.log('checking online opponents with:', onOnlineCheckPacket);
                    websocket.send(onOnlineCheckPacket);
                    monitor = initScrollMonitor();
                };


                window.onbeforeunload = function () {

                    var onClosePacket = JSON.stringify({
                        type: "offline",
                        session_key: '{{ request.session.session_key }}',
                        username: opponent_username,
                        {# Sending username because to let opponnent know that the user went offline #}
                    });
                    console.log('unloading, sending:', onClosePacket);
                    websocket.send(onClosePacket);
                    websocket.close();
                };


                websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
                    var packet;

                    try {
                        packet = JSON.parse(event.data);
                        console.log(packet)
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    }

                    switch (packet.type) {
                        case "new-dialog":
                            // TODO: add new dialog to dialog_list
                            break;
                        case "user-not-found":
                            // TODO: dispay some kind of an error that the user is not found
                            break;
                        case "gone-online":
                            if (packet.usernames.indexOf(opponent_username) != -1) {
                                gone_online();
                            } else {
                                gone_offline();
                            }
                            for (var i = 0; i < packet.usernames.length; ++i) {
                                setUserOnlineOffline(packet.usernames[i], true);
                            }
                            break;
                        case "gone-offline":
                            if (packet.username == opponent_username) {
                                gone_offline();
                            }
                            setUserOnlineOffline(packet.username, false);
                            break;
                        case "new-message":
                            if (packet['sender_name'] == opponent_username || packet['sender_name'] == $("#owner_username").val()) {
                                addNewMessage(packet);
                                if (packet['sender_name'] == opponent_username) {
                                    initReadMessageHandler(monitor, $("div[data-id='" + packet['message_id'] + "']"));
                                }
                            } else {
                                flash_user_button(packet['sender_name']);
                            }
                            break;
                        case "opponent-typing":
                            var typing_elem = $('#typing-text');
                            if (!typing_elem.is(":visible")) {
                                typing_elem.fadeIn(500);
                            } else {
                                typing_elem.stop(true);
                                typing_elem.fadeIn(0);
                            }
                            typing_elem.fadeOut(3000);
                            break;
                        case "opponent-read-message":
                            if (packet['username'] == opponent_username) {
                                $("div[data-id='" + packet['message_id'] + "']").removeClass('msg-unread').addClass('msg-read');
                            }
                            break;

                        default:
                            console.log('error: ', event)
                    }
                }
            }

            function sendMessage(message) {
                var opponent_username = getOpponnentUsername();
                var newMessagePacket = JSON.stringify({
                    type: 'new-message',
                    session_key: '{{ request.session.session_key }}',
                    username: opponent_username,
                    message: message
                });
                websocket.send(newMessagePacket)
            }

            $('#chat-message').keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13 && this.value) {
                    sendMessage(this.value);
                    this.value = "";
                    return false
                } else {
                    var opponent_username = getOpponnentUsername();
                    var packet = JSON.stringify({
                        type: 'is-typing',
                        session_key: '{{ request.session.session_key }}',
                        username: opponent_username,
                        typing: true
                    });
                    websocket.send(packet);
                }
            });

            $('#btn-send-message').click(function (e) {
                var $chatInput = $('#chat-message');
                var msg = $chatInput.val();
                if (!msg) return;
                sendMessage($chatInput.val());
                $chatInput.val('')
            });

            setupChatWebSocket();
            scrollToLastMessage();
        });

    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html:

```
 {% load static %}

    <!-- Their site uses old school block layout -->
    {% block extra_js %}

        <!-- Your package using 2SoD block layout -->
        {% block javascript %}
            <script src="{% static 'js/ninja.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        {% endblock javascript %}

    {% endblock extra_js %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are calling {{ block.super }} on a base template.

You should include a base template using {% extends "base_template_name.html" %} before calling {{ block.super }}.

This would include content from the super template ("base_template_name.html") in your "dialog.html" template, instead of overriding it. You may also try just removing or commenting out the {{ block.super }} call if you don't need any content from the super template.

Please post your code here if you still can't get it to work. Hope it works for you!

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block css %}
    <link href="{% static "django_private_chat/css/django_private_chat.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
{% endblock css %}
```

Comment: it not worked me i had posted my dialogs and base.html please help me

Comment: @sssss Did you wrap your extends call correctly in dialogs.html? {% extends "base.html" %}

Comment: Yes @Andries I just downloaded and added in my project thats it

Comment: Yes Now I am getting TemplateDoesNotExist at /dialogs/
base.html this error

Comment: @sssss you also need to ensure that you use {{ block.super }} in a correctly named block. You are calling {{ block.super }} in {% block css %} in your dialog.html template, but your "base.html" file does not have a {% block css %} block instantiated, therefore the call from {{ block.super }} seems to fail.

Comment: Now where should I call @Andries

Comment: @sssss from your code I would recommend you remove {{ block.super }} completely. You are not calling any css from your base.html template. Let me know if that works?

Comment: Yes I had removed I am getting the blank page @Andries

Comment: But I need to get something why I am not getting anything@Andries

Comment: @sssss could you post some more screenshots? Also check your Chrome/Firefox developer tools for any Javascript errors?

Comment: Yes I had included the error in chrom developer tools please see and help me

Comment: @sssss yes it seems to be a Javascript error. Django is now successfully rendering the template, but the JS error causes a blank page, as nothing can be rendered on the DOM. May I suggest you start a new question thread for this issue as it no longer relates to the original problem?